# After visibility hidden I am not able to change the checkbox

Tags: html, css

I want to style with CSS my checkbox. To be true, I have an image, I want to put insted of my checkbox. But after I use `visibility: hidden` or `display_none` I can not put anything in replace. Could you help me?

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="contact_dane">

          <input type="checkbox" id="contact_data" checked>
          <label for="contact_data">
            <span>
              Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
            </span>
          </label>

            </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
.contact_dane input[type="checkbox"] {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.contact_data input[type="checkbox"] + label span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("ok.jpg") left top no-repeat;
}
```

//edit: sorry, I was trying to simplify my question, and I forgot to change the css class names, now it's ok.

Comment: try use javacript.

Comment: use display:none and what do you mean you can't replace? also your css names aren't the same as the class names in the html.

Comment: Thanks for the css names, as I write in edit, I was trying to simplify the question and forgot to change the css names.
With "can't replace" I mean that in all of the tutorials I saw, it was exactly like that and the css were replaced with the background I set. In my case, the checkbox disappears and nothing shows instead.

Comment: can you press f12 and check the network. i suspect ok.jpg can't be found, maybe try a color instead of an image and see if that does work.

Comment: I put color instead of image: still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

see that checked attribute

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="contact_data" checked>
```

it should be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="contact_data" checked="expression">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: none;` on you checkbox. Also i recommend wrap your `input` with `span` in `label` like this:

```
<div class="contact_dane">
  <label for="contact_data">
    <input type="checkbox" id="contact_data" checked>
      <span>
        Lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
      </span>
    </label>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.contact_dane input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
}

.contact_dane label span:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: url("ok.jpg") left top no-repeat;
}
```

JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rx7u3hqL/)

Comment: It's still nothing, not even an empty place in the original, not styled checkbox. Like after display: none it disappears and nothing happens instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that with a background image. Try one this examples to style it only with css:

- http://www.inserthtml.com/2012/06/custom-form-radio-checkbox/
- http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953